# Error handling in Lambda with API Gateway proxy integration

Tags: python, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

From what I understand, when using Lambda proxy integration one must return `statusCode` and `body` in order to return any meaningful error information to the HTTP client.

My python code is below:

```
import json
import traceback

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    try:
        result = business_logic()        
        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': json.dumps(result)    
        }

    except Exception as e:
        error = {
            "type": e.__class__.__name__,
            "message": str(e),
            "traceback": traceback.format_exc()
        }
        return {
            'statusCode': 502,
            'body': json.dumps(error)
        }
```

My problem is, I'd like to make use of Lambda and Cloudwatch's handy monitoring interface (e.g. being able to trigger off lambda errors) but since lambda in this code is handling all errors and returning a value, I think lambda will have 0% error rate.

Is there an alternative approach which still uses proxy integration and passes error info?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to check your metrics, it's better to check API Gateway's cloudwatch than Lambda's.

Unless you really really want Lambda's cloudwatch to monitor errorrs, you might have through non-proxy integration

Comment: The challenge with API Gateway's Cloudwatch is that AFAICT it doesn't have granularity to distinguish performance at the resource level. It seems you get error rates for the whole API only, so you have no easy way to know which of your API's resources has an elevated failure rate without integrating a third party solution (e.g. Sentry.io) into your lambda fn.

Comment: That makes sense. You can opt to not use proxy integration, use the normal integration and mess around with mapping templates so that you can at least have control on those pesky 2xx http status.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit messier, but since the lambda is responsible for the error handling in the code(response codes/etc.) it might have to also be responsible for creating the metrics than.

You can simply generate the metric via the SDK, for example:

```
def handler(event: Dict[str, Any], context: LambdaContext) -> Dict:
    try:
        raise Exception( "")
    except Exception:
        client = boto3.client('cloudwatch')
        response = client.put_metric_data(Namespace=‘my_namespace’, MetricData=[
            {
                'MetricName': f”my_metric",
                'Value': 1,
                'Timestamp': time.time()
            }
        ])
        return ResponseUtil.build_exception_response(logger)
```